# Квадрат чисел строки

Tags: python

Не могу понять почему не работает
идея такая, есть число 123 надо вывести 149

```
def sqr(n):
    return (n*n for n in n)
print(sqr(123).split())
```

Comment: Так число или строка? Это абсолютно разные типы, с числом нельзя работать как со строкой, со строкой нельзя работать как с числом, определитесь

Answer (score 3):

Как вам правильно написали в комментарии, в питоне может быть число `123`, а может быть строка `"123"`.

Возводить в квадрат можно только числа, а делать split - только для строк. Чтобы преобразовать число в строку, служит функция `str()`. Чтобы преобразовать строку в целое число (если для данной строки это возможно) - `int()`.

Впрочем, если вы собираетесь итерироваться по буквам строки, `split` и не нужен - для строк и так уже реализован такой тип итерирования по умолчанию.

А вот склеить потом отдельные буквы с помощью функции `join` - нужно. Если вы, конечно, хотите получить в результате `123`, а не `[1, 2, 3]`

И ещё одно замечание - вы в генераторном выражении используете одно и тоже имя и для той переменной, по которой итерируетесь, и для переменной с текущим элементом. Это будет работать, но крайне рекомендуется для этого использовать два разных имени.

В итоге код для вашей задачи будет таким:

```
def sqr(s):
    return ''.join(str(int(с)**2) for с in s)

res = sqr(str(123))

print(res)
```